# Django Allauth, Twitter Scope

Tags: django, twitter-oauth, django-allauth

I'd like to get the user email from the twitter oauth. So I requested this in the app settings.

[image]

I added the scope (to settings.py):

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'linkedin': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'r_emailaddress',
            'r_basicprofile',
            'r_fullprofile',
        ],
        'PROFILE_FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'first-name',
            'last-name',
            'positions',
            'email-address',
            'picture-url',
            'public-profile-url',
            'headline',
            'skills',
            'summary',
            'location',
            'industry',
            'positions',
            'company',
            'specialties',
            'public-profile-url',
        ],
        'LOCATION_FIELDS': [
            'location',
        ],
        'POSITION_FIELDS': [
            'company',
        ]
    },

    'twitter': {
        'SCOPE': ['email'],
    },
}
```

However, I'm still having the user data like the name, picture ..etc but not the email.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Have you set the `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED` setting?

Comment: No. But thanks, it works like this.